# Vim: Receive char on function to tabularize

Tags: vim, alignment, tabular

I learned that using this:

```
let mapleader=','
if exists(":Tabularize")
  nmap <Leader>a= :Tabularize /=<CR>
  vmap <Leader>a= :Tabularize /=<CR>
endif
```

would give me a shortcut to tabularize with the '=' char. But I'd like to **generalize** it, so that I could use some shortcut like:

```
<Leader>a$
<Leader>a*
```

And it would read the '$' or '*' char and use it as the "char to tabularize". I.e., pass this char to the `:Tabularize /CHAR` function

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put that if block in your vimrc it will never work, because vimrc is sourced before any plugins, so the *:Tabularize* command doesn't exist yet when the expresion `exists(':Tabularize')` is evaluated and it will always be false.

You could use these mappings:

```
nnoremap <Leader>a :Tabularize /
vnoremap <Leader>a :Tabularize /
```

So when you press <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> you'll be left in in command line mode with `:Tabularize /*`, ready to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: thank you for fixing it, and for tip. I ended up with: `nmap <Leader>t :Tabularize /`